# Browser geolocation - Android 2.3.4 ignores GPS satellites. How to fix?

Tags: android, geolocation

Is there a recognized problem with geolocation via the default browser in Android 2.3.4 Gingerbread?

On an HTC G2 android 2.3.4, the default browser does not appear to use the GPS satellites to determine location.  As a result, the location the browser sends to the app is off by a mile or so.  Yes, the GPS and wi-fi were both on in the phone.  We turned wi-fi off and got the same (bad) result.

Is there some voodoo that can be done to get the default browser in 2.3.4 to do proper geolocation?

On an iPhone 3s geolocation with the very same browser app works perfectly.  The following link starts the Gmap4 app (I am the developer) and shows your location on the Google 'Hybrid" map:
http://www.mappingsupport.com/p/gmap4.php?mylocation=on

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not a browser problem, but a phone specific issue. If you are getting a position off by a mile, for sure the position has been acquired from wifi.

When you start the map, it tries to get the `LastKnownLocation`, and if it's to old it reverts to wifi position. Now, if you turn wifi off, the position acquiried using wi-fi will remain available as a recent `LastKnownLocation` and will be used to position the map again.

Until you get a better position from GPS this one will be used.

At least some phones discard the `LastKnownLocation` when you restart them. You can try it, with wifi off, to see what happens.

Regards.